# Work on localhost, on domain not working. Connection timeout?

Tags: server, apache2

Website work on localhost:33333 but if I run `my.domain.com:33333` or `my.domain.com` not working.(`Connection timeout`)

What could be the reason?

```
<VirtualHost *:33333>
ServerName my.domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/vtigercrm/
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/vtiger.my.domain.com.error_log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/vtiger.my.domain.com.access_log combined
<Directory /var/www/vtigercrm>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

`grep -iR listen /etc/apache2/` output:

```
/etc/apache2/ports.conf:Listen 33333
/etc/apache2/ports.conf:    Listen 443
/etc/apache2/ports.conf:    Listen 443
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections, and which
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:# Include list of ports to listen on and which to use for name based vhosts
```

/var/log/apache2/error.log

```
[Mon May 06 19:27:17 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.4.6-1ubuntu1.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon May 06 19:41:52 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon May 06 19:41:53 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.4.6-1ubuntu1.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

`iptables -L -nv`: http://wklej.org/hash/8f77aa0dbc6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your firewall doesn't allow port 33333. Run:

```
sudo ufw allow 33333/tcp
```

to open it.